# DAX function to show '-' / 'No value' when multiple checkboxes are selected

Tags: powerbi

I am working on a task in Power BI where I have to show  `Case 1: "-" (No value) when I select all values Case 2: "-" (No value) when I select multiple check boxes  Case 3: BDM Name when I select 1 check box`

I'm using the below codes but they both are not working -

`Code 1 - C_BDM = IF( HASONEFILTER('All Details - Raw'[Producer Code]), 'All Details - Raw'[BDM], "-")`

`Code 2 - C_BDM = SWITCH(TRUE(), ISFILTERED('All Details - Raw'[Producer Code]),'All Details - Raw'[BDM],"-")`

Any ideas as to how I can get it to display BDM when I select just 1 check box?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Code =
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( 'All Details - Raw'[Producer Code] ),
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'All Details - Raw'[BDM], "-" ),
    "-"
)
```

Comment: This code is showing "-" at all times, i.e when I select all values, multiple checkboxes or a single check box.

Comment: That means you don't have a unique BDM when a Producer Code is selected. Which BDM should it display in this case?

Comment: It should display the first BDM that it available.

Comment: Then try MIN() or MAX() instead of SELECTEDVALUE(, "-").

Comment: I tried using the the MIN() instead of SELECTEDVALUE(). However, it is still returning "-" for all different cases.

Comment: If it's returning "-" when you only have one `'All Details - Raw'[Producer Code]` selected, then something is going wrong in a way that I can't diagnose without seeing the file.

Comment: I would have shared the file but it is confidential to the company, so I can't. Thank you for your time though. Appreciate it. :)